# QuerySelectorAll not working, but QuerySelector works with .replace or .replaceAll

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to javascript and trying some things to learn. I'm however getting one issue and can't seem to figure it out.
If I'm looking trough the nodelist with `document.querySelectorAll(".product .actions .stock.outofstock")` I get 10 results back:

[image]

I want to replace the inside from all these elements to something new.

I tried using the following:

```
let outofstock = document.querySelectorAll(".product.actions.stock.outofstock").innerHTML;
document.querySelectorAll(".product.actions.stock.outofstock").innerHTML= outofstock.replace(/Out of stock/g,'<i class="icon-negative"></i>Sold out');
```

That didnt work and gives me the following error:

[image]

however when I use the following code it works, but for only the first element:

```
let outofstock = document.querySelector(".product.actions.stock.outofstock").innerHTML;
document.querySelector(".product.actions.stock.outofstock").innerHTML= outofstock.replace(/Out of stock/g,'<i class="icon-negative"></i>Sold out');
```

Comment: use replaceAll property of javascript.

Comment: or iterate thru the array you are getting back.

Comment: @ShilpeSaxena that doesnt work either. It gives back the same error but then 'Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replaceAll')

Comment: @E.Maggini Do you have an example for that?

Comment: `const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".product.actions.stock.outofstock"); for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) { /* do stuff with elements[i] */ }` or even `for (const element of elements) { /* do stuff with element */ }`

Comment: or map....or filter....or forEach.... really....Google is such a powerful tool.....

Comment: @VLAZ why close it only to (kinda) answer it in the comments? :-D

Comment: @E.Maggini Google is really powerfull, but no clue on how to google this specific issue. Been doing that for the past 2 hours with no results haha

Comment: @E.Maggini because OP asked in the comments. And also put the question up for reopening. This is an attempt to notify reopen reviewers that the duplicate closure is correct.

Comment: @Nickinatorz try to do it in console area console.log(yourVariableName.replaceAll(val, chnageVal))